# Crop an HBITMAP with C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi

I have an `HBITMAP` holding the screenshot of a window. Now I want to crop a certain region/rectangle out of it and return it as a new `HBITMAP`.

The following code however only squeezes the image into the correct new rectangle size but does not crop it:

```
HBITMAP crop_image(const RECT rectangle, const HBITMAP source_image)
{
    const auto h_clone = static_cast<HBITMAP>(CopyImage(source_image, IMAGE_BITMAP, rectangle.right - rectangle.left,
                                                        rectangle.bottom - rectangle.top, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION));

    const auto hdc_mem = CreateCompatibleDC(nullptr);
    const auto hdc_mem2 = CreateCompatibleDC(nullptr);

    const auto h_old_bmp = static_cast<HBITMAP>(SelectObject(hdc_mem, source_image));
    const auto h_old_bmp2 = static_cast<HBITMAP>(SelectObject(hdc_mem2, h_clone));

    BitBlt(hdc_mem2, 0, 0, rectangle.right - rectangle.left, rectangle.bottom - rectangle.top,
           hdc_mem, rectangle.left, rectangle.top, SRCCOPY);

    SelectObject(hdc_mem, h_old_bmp);
    SelectObject(hdc_mem2, h_old_bmp2);

    DeleteDC(hdc_mem);
    DeleteDC(hdc_mem2);

    return h_clone;
}
```

How can I fix my code to crop the image as desired?

Comment: CopyImage() is the bug, it stretches the image.  Hard to guess why it is there, copying is BitBlt's job.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this going to work or not due to I haven't been working on Win32 for a long time, so let's try.

Here is the idea:

1. Create a new memory DC.
2. Create a new bitmap instead of cloning from the source.
3. `BitBlt` the target rectangle of the source bitmap into the one that just created.

**Create a new DC and bitmap**

Use `CreateCompatibleDC` as you did to create a memory DC. Then create a new bitmap with `CreateCompatibleBitmap`. The width and height of the bitmap will be the size of the cropped bitmap. Then select it into the DC with `SelectObject`.

**Copy the target rectangle from the source**

Now you need to create a new DC for the source bitmap with `CreateCompatibleDC` and select the source bitmap into it with `SelectObject`. Then use `BitBlt` to copy the rectangle of the source bitmap into the bitmap that you just created. The destination `x` and `y` will be zero because we want to start drawing from the upper-left. The source `x` and `y` is where you want to start copy from the source bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be reduced to this:

```
HBITMAP crop_image(const RECT rectangle, const HBITMAP source_image)
{
    const auto h_clone = static_cast<HBITMAP>(CopyImage(source_image, IMAGE_BITMAP, rectangle.right - rectangle.left,
                                                        rectangle.bottom - rectangle.top, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION));    

    return h_clone;
}
```

The deleted code doesn't do anything useful. After I test, I can get the cropped area, not the reduced screenshot. Because you didn't provide the complete code, I couldn't get more conclusions.

For the process of clipping screenshots, we can easily modify it according to the official example.

[Capturing an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image)

The APIs used are described in detail in the example.

You only need to change some of the code, such as changing the cropped area, and the example also shows how to save the cropped area as a file.

```
int CaptureAnImage(HWND hWnd)
{
    HDC hdcScreen;
    HDC hdcWindow;
    HDC hdcMemDC = NULL;
    HBITMAP hbmScreen = NULL;
    BITMAP bmpScreen;
    RECT rc;
    rc.left = 0;
    rc.top = 0;
    rc.right = 800;
    rc.bottom = 600;

    // Retrieve the handle to a display device context for the client 
    // area of the window. 
    hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
    hdcWindow = GetDC(hWnd);

    // Create a compatible DC which is used in a BitBlt from the window DC
    hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);

    if (!hdcMemDC)
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"CreateCompatibleDC has failed", L"Failed", MB_OK);
    }

    // Get the client area for size calculation
    RECT rcClient;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);

    //This is the best stretch mode
    SetStretchBltMode(hdcWindow, HALFTONE);

    //The source DC is the entire screen and the destination DC is the current window (HWND)
    if (!StretchBlt(hdcWindow,
        0, 0,
        rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom,
        hdcScreen,
        0, 0,
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN),
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN),
        SRCCOPY))
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"StretchBlt has failed", L"Failed", MB_OK);
    }

    // Create a compatible bitmap from the Window DC
    hbmScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);

    if (!hbmScreen)
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"CreateCompatibleBitmap Failed", L"Failed", MB_OK);
    }

    // Select the compatible bitmap into the compatible memory DC.
    SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hbmScreen);

    // Bit block transfer into our compatible memory DC.


    if (!BitBlt(hdcMemDC,
        rc.left, rc.top,
        rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top,
        hdcWindow,
        0, 0,
        SRCCOPY))
    {
        MessageBox(hWnd, L"BitBlt has failed", L"Failed", MB_OK);
    }



//  HBITMAP bmpnew = crop_image(rc, hbmScreen);

    // Get the BITMAP from the HBITMAP
    GetObject(hbmScreen, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmpScreen);

    BITMAPFILEHEADER   bmfHeader;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER   bi;

    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = bmpScreen.bmWidth;
    bi.biHeight = bmpScreen.bmHeight;
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    DWORD dwBmpSize = ((bmpScreen.bmWidth * bi.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4 * bmpScreen.bmHeight;

    // Starting with 32-bit Windows, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc are implemented as wrapper functions that 
    // call HeapAlloc using a handle to the process's default heap. Therefore, GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc 
    // have greater overhead than HeapAlloc.
    HANDLE hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND, dwBmpSize);
    char *lpbitmap = (char *)GlobalLock(hDIB);

    // Gets the "bits" from the bitmap and copies them into a buffer 
    // which is pointed to by lpbitmap.
    GetDIBits(hdcWindow, hbmScreen, 0,
        (UINT)bmpScreen.bmHeight,
        lpbitmap,
        (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    // A file is created, this is where we will save the screen capture.
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"captureqwsx.bmp",
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    // Add the size of the headers to the size of the bitmap to get the total file size
    DWORD dwSizeofDIB = dwBmpSize + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    //Offset to where the actual bitmap bits start.
    bmfHeader.bfOffBits = (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    //Size of the file
    bmfHeader.bfSize = dwSizeofDIB;

    //bfType must always be BM for Bitmaps
    bmfHeader.bfType = 0x4D42; //BM   

    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bmfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(hFile, (LPSTR)lpbitmap, dwBmpSize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

    //Unlock and Free the DIB from the heap
    GlobalUnlock(hDIB);
    GlobalFree(hDIB);

    //Close the handle for the file that was created
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    //Clean up
    DeleteObject(hbmScreen);
    DeleteObject(hdcMemDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow);

    return 0;
}
```

It will get a cropped screenshot(800x600) file of the current screen.

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza Hi, does this answer help you?